# Flutter Bloc - How to show keep showing error when submit is fail

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm learning bloc and using equatable.

here is my code

*login_state.dart*

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

abstract class LoginState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoginInitial extends LoginState {}

class LoginLoading extends LoginState {}

class LoginSuccess extends LoginState {
  final Map token;

  LoginSuccess({@required this.token});
}

class LoginFailure extends LoginState {
  final Map error;

  LoginFailure({@required this.error});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => null;
}
```

*login_view*

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool loading = _authStore.loading;

    return BlocProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => _loginBloc,
        child: BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
          listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
            if (state is LoginFailure) {
              print("loginFailure is triggered with ${state.error}");
              FlashAlert(context: context, message: state.error['message']).showFlash();
            }
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            ),
            body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: spacing(3)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: spacing(2)),
              child: widget.isLogin ? loginView() : registerView(),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {
                widget.isLogin ? handleLogin('') : handleRegister();
              },
              child: loading ? Progress() : Icon(EvaIcons.arrowIosForward),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

I've tried putting [error] on get props.

```
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
```

The problem is `FlashAlert` is only run 1 times when error occur. How can I keep using equatable but keep triggering the `FlashAlert` when error occur?.

THanks.

----- edit using blocbuilder ---

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool loading = _authStore.loading;

    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => _loginBloc,
      child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(builder: (BuildContext context, state) {
        if (state is LoginFailure) {
          print("loginFailure is triggered with ${state.error}");

          FlashAlert(context: context, message: state.error['message']).showFlash();
        }

        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: spacing(3)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: spacing(2)),
            child: widget.isLogin ? loginView() : registerView(),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.isLogin ? handleLogin('') : handleRegister();
            },
            child: state is LoginLoading ? Progress() : Icon(EvaIcons.arrowIosForward),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

return error:

`VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#21a25]`

Comment: Show your LoginBloc file

Comment: A quick workaround would be yield `LoginLoading`, and then `LoginFailure` to force the update, or add a special state `LoginFailureBuffing` to keep It logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using BlocListener that's why you are facing this error.BlocListener will only execute once only.

Following lines are from official documentation.

> BlocListener is a Flutter widget which takes a BlocWidgetListener and
>   an optional Bloc and invokes the listener in response to state changes
>   in the bloc. **It should be used for functionality that needs to occur
>   once per state change** such as navigation, showing a SnackBar, showing
>   a Dialog, etc...

You can use **BlocBuilder** and it will solve your issue.

Update:

This is happening because when build method call at that time your are trying to show FlashAlert, so you can avoid it by adding wait of 1 microsecond.

call following method instead on doing in bloc.

```
 void callme() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));
    if (state is LoginFailure) {
      print("loginFailure is triggered with ${state.error}");

      FlashAlert(context: context, message: state.error['message']).showFlash();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've add if (state is LoginFailure) {
            print("loginFailure is triggered with ${state.error}");

            FlashAlert(context: context, message: state.error['message']).showFlash();
          } to BlocBuilder, it return me Failed assertion: line 3803 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Comment: thread updated with blocbuilder. error added. sorry forget to paste it in.